# Chartkick for Newsletters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

Is it possible to use [Chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) without rails? I would like to write a ruby script that generates a HTML newsletter which can be send by mail. The output should be a HTML file.

How do I integrate Chartkick into my project and supply it with the data needed?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use chartkick without rails i'll show you basic example from there you can go to this link for more http://www.stuartellis.name/articles/erb/ 
  inside irb type this

```
require 'chartkick'
include Chartkick::Helper
@data = [
  ["Washington", "1789-04-29", "1797-03-03"],
  ["Adams", "1797-03-03", "1801-03-03"],
  ["Jefferson", "1801-03-03", "1809-03-03"]
]
template = "<%= timeline @data%>"
renderer = ERB.new(template)
puts renderer.result()
```

This gives you html and js you need, but you have to include js manually

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="chartkick.js"></script>
```

which you can download here [chartkick](https://raw.github.com/ankane/chartkick/master/app/assets/javascripts/chartkick.js)

on a side note:
you dont even need to use ruby it's just javascript library [chartkick.js](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js)